# each() jquery issue

Tags: jquery, each

SUre I am missing something with this Jquery. Suppose I have a list of n words as so : `<div class ="text"><p>word(n)</p></div>`. I want to alert each of the words so I put simply :

```
var string= $('.text p');
string.each(function(){ldelim}
alert($(this).val());
{rdelim}
);
```

{rdelim} and {ldelim} are just left braces and right braces because I use smarty. But the alert returns an empty message. Someone could help ?

Comment: string is a reserved keyword, use an other

Comment: Are you sure that in your actually code don't have the "{ldelim}" and "{rdelim}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string= $('.text p');
string.each(function(i,v){ldelim}
    alert($(v).text());
{rdelim}
);
```

this should work :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `text` method, `val` is used for setting/getting values of form elements:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Comment: Ok thanks it worked, but why .val() doesn(t work, I used it a hundred times on this kind of stuffs ?

Comment: val is for input to get text of div, p  or another element like span etc use text()

Answer (score 1):

Use this flow:

```
var string= $('.text p');
 $.each(string,function(k,v){                        
 alert(v.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way :

```
$(function(){

$.each($('.text p'),function(){
alert($(this).html())
});

});
```